# Wordpress: Using post navigation with css classes instead of text

Tags: css, wordpress, custom-post-type

In Wordpress, I have created a custom post type. For navigation I created a left and a right arrow with pure CSS, `.arrow_left` and `.arrow_right`.

My CSS:

```
.arrow_left {
  position:absolute;
  left:10px;
  top:5px;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent; 
  border-right:10px solid lightgrey; 
}

.arrow_right {
  position:absolute;
  right:10px;
  top:5px;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent; 
  border-left:10px solid lightgrey; 
}
```

Now I would like to attach the navigation functionality to these CSS arrows. I tried out the following:

```
<?php previous_post_link('%link','<div class="arrow_left"></div>'); ?>
<?php next_post_link('%link','<div class="arrow_right"></div>'); ?>
```

My problem: When applying this code, both arrows disappear. What's wrong about the code?

Comment: Could you post your `arrow_left` CSS?

Comment: @AndyM I just added the CSS

Comment: Okay. This looks like it can be fixed. I'm slammed at work right now, but I'll see if I can get an answer up this afternoon.

Comment: @AndyM very nice from you. I already found a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22710460/wp-previous-next-post-as-link-in-a-tag

Comment: Okay, I'm glad you figured it out.