# WP: Previous/next post as link in <a>-tag

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

Custom Post Types in Wordpress: Is it possible to integrate a navigation functionality into the `<a>`-tag of an element ?

Let's say in the *single-customposttype.php* file I have a coloured box. When you click on it the next post of the custom post type must appear.

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
<a href="<?php $link_next = get_next_posts_link(); echo $link_next ?>"><div class="red_box"></div></a>
```

Anyone knows the correct code?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_next_post

Comment: @Matthijs I had a look at it, but it won't help me

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. A possible solution can be something like this:

```
    <?php $prev = get_permalink(get_adjacent_post(false,'',false)); 
    if ($prev != get_permalink()) { ?><a href="<?php echo $prev; ?>"><div class="arrow_left"></div></a><?php } ?>

    <?php $next = get_permalink(get_adjacent_post(false,'',true)); 
    if ($next != get_permalink()) { ?><a href="<?php echo $next; ?>"><div class="arrow_right"></div></a><?php } ?>
```